# SpaCy: How to get the spacy model name?

Tags: python, spacy

It doesn't show up in `pip list`

```
zeke$ pip list | grep spacy
spacy (1.7.3)
```

**How do I get the name of the model?**

---

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
echo "spaCy model:"
python3 -m sputnik --name spacy find
```

Throws up this error:

```
zeke$ python3 -m sputnik --name spacy find
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zeke/anaconda/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/zeke/anaconda/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/zeke/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sputnik/__main__.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/zeke/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sputnik/__main__.py", line 12, in main
    args.run(args)
  File "/Users/zeke/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sputnik/cli.py", line 89, in run
    data_path=args.data_path)
  File "/Users/zeke/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sputnik/__init__.py", line 114, in find
    obj = cls(app_name, app_version, expand_path(data_path))
  File "/Users/zeke/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sputnik/pool.py", line 19, in __init__
    super(Pool, self).__init__(app_name, app_version, path, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/zeke/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sputnik/package_list.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "/Users/zeke/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sputnik/package_list.py", line 51, in load
    for package in self.packages():
  File "/Users/zeke/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sputnik/package_list.py", line 47, in packages
    yield self.__class__.package_class(path=os.path.join(self.path, path))
  File "/Users/zeke/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sputnik/package.py", line 15, in __init__
    super(Package, self).__init__(defaults=meta['package'])
KeyError: 'package'
```

Comment: I think the answer that link below will do the job: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75824689/9780575

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `sputnik` package manager is deprecated as of spaCy version 1.7.0. In your version, you should be able to see all installed / linked models using `spacy info`:

```
python -m spacy info     # info about spaCy and installed models
python -m spacy info en  # info about model with the shortcut link 'en'
```

All model meta is also exposed as the `meta` attribute of the `Language` class, so from within your script, you can do:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en') # or any other model
print(nlp.meta['name'])
```

If you have downloaded models via spaCy's new `download` command, they'll be installed as pip packages. This means that they should show up when you run `pip list` or `pip freeze` from within the same environment.

Note that models are not downloaded automatically when you install spaCy, so you have to download them separately (see [the docs](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/models) for a list of available models):

```
python -m spacy download en              # default English model (~50MB)
python -m spacy download en_core_web_md  # larger English model (~1GB)
```

Comment: wooo, yeah its showing up in `pip list` as `en-core-web-sm (1.2.0)`; I just missed it...! :/