# Find out all the language models installed in spacy

Tags: python, spacy

I work with Spacy in several languages and I have different language models installed in computer A or computer B.

Often times I would like just to list all the languages models installed in a particular virtual environment.

Is there something like spacy list language-models installed in the command line?

(In https://spacy.io/usage/models does not seem to be an answer for that)

Comment: `spacy validate` or `python -m spacy validate` depending on your environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do the job.

```
import spacy

spacy.info()['pipelines'].keys()
```

[List spacy's languages models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHQD8.png)